Perturbation Theory of Algebraic equation
I am trying to solve
\begin{equation}
    q(x)=x^3+c_0x^2\frac{1}{n^{a}}+c_0x\frac{1}{n^{a}}=\frac{\ell}{n}
\end{equation}
Where $0\leq a \leq 1$.
As $n\rightarrow\infty$
I find if $a\leq \frac{1}{2}$ then a solution is $x=\frac{\ell}{n^{1-a} c_0}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ell}{n^{2-2a}}\right)$
While if
$a\geq \frac{2}{3}$ then a solution looks like $x=\left(\frac{\ell}{n}\right)^{1/3}+\mathcal{O}\left( \left( \frac{\ell}{n}\right)^{2/3} \right)$.
Can someone tell we how to obtain this for all the range of $a$, without a computer software?

For the first one, power series reversion gives  $\frac{\ell n^{a-1}}{c_0}$.

@ClaudeLeibovici can you kindly elaborate?

This equation is a cubic equation in function of $x$. I think with $(a,b,c,d) = (1,c_0/n^a,c_0/n^a,-l/n)$, this equation has 1 unique real solution. It is possible to use Cardano formula to obtain the analytical solution and after that, it suffices to apply the Taylor series expansion.

@NN2 It get's really completed due to the square roots and the cube roots

Changing notations
$$\alpha=\frac {c_0}{n^a} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=-\frac{\ell}n$$ consider the function
$$f(x)=x^3+\alpha x^2+\alpha x +\beta$$ Consider that this is
$$f(x)=\beta +\alpha  x+\alpha x^2+x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and use power series reversion to obtain
$$x=\frac{f(x)-\beta }{\alpha }-\frac{(f(x)-\beta)^2}{\alpha ^2}+
\frac{(2 \alpha -1) (f(x)-\beta)^3}{\alpha ^4}+O\left((f(x)-\beta )^4\right)$$ Since we want $f(x)=0$, this reduces to
$$x=-\frac{\beta }{\alpha }-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha ^2}-
\frac{(2 \alpha -1) \beta^3}{\alpha ^4}+O\left(\beta ^4\right)$$ Truncating to first order and back to the original parameters
$$x \sim \frac{\ell}{c_0\,n^{1-a}}+O\Bigg(\frac{\ell^2}{c_0^2\,n^{2(1-a)}}  \Bigg)$$

Hi @Claude. Thanks for your detailed response.
I must tell you that I am sending $n\rightarrow\infty$,
But I see the solution behaving like $\frac{\ell}{c_0 n^{1-a}}$ for $a<\frac{1}{2}$ and behaving like $\frac{\ell^{1/3}}{n^{1/3}}$ for $a>\frac{2}{3}$, how to see this?
